# New page is not loading in html

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Through my web page i'm updating my database and once the database is updated a new page will open.Everything is happening i.e. database i getting updated,all values are getting printed etc. but the new page is not opening,the same page is getting refreshed.Also i'm getting a status of 0.Here is my code.

```
      try{
                console.log("here1 "+email);
                get1.open("GET","/Livie_project1/Check2?id="+email+"&id1="+parms["name"][0],true);
                }catch(Exception )
                {
                    console.log("error11");
                }
                get1.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log(this.readyState+" get1 "+this.status);
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                window.open("/Livie_project1/index.html?name="+email,"_self");
                console.log("matched");
                var JSONtopicobject=eval( "("+this.responseText + ")" );
                var t=JSONtopicobject.topic.name;
                var t2=JSONtopicobject.topic.name1;
                console.log(t2+" "+t);
                }};
            try{
                get1.send(null);
                }catch(Exception)
                {
                    console.log("erro12");
                }
```

As seen in the code all values are getting printed i.e matched is getting printed which is just below the window.open() function.The address of the page is correct as i'm not getting any error in the console.
Please let me know what mistake i'm doing.Please help.

This is the servlet part

```
          public class Check2 extends HttpServlet {
           String pwd;
           @Override
           protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {      
            String name=req.getParameter("id"); 
            String name1=req.getParameter("id1"); 
            Connection con=null;        
            Statement stmt=null;        
            PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();        

            try{
                //get a connection
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login","root","ATul1996@@");
               //Execute a query
                int count=0;
                stmt=con.createStatement();    
                String query ="update login set pwd="+"\""+name+"\""+" where email = "+"\""+name1+"\"" ;
                int j=stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            }        
            catch(SQLException e)        
                {
                    out.println(e);               
                }

            res.setContentType("text/html");
            StringBuffer  returndata =new StringBuffer("{\"topic\":{");
            returndata.append("\"name\": ");
            returndata.append("\"");
            returndata.append(name);
            returndata.append("\"");
            returndata.append(",");
            returndata.append("\"name1\": ");
            returndata.append("\"");
            returndata.append(name1);
            returndata.append("\"");
            returndata.append("}}");
            res.getWriter().write(returndata.toString());
            res.getWriter().flush();
            res.getWriter().close();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code

```
  window.open("/Livie_project1/index.html.html?name="+email,"_self");
```

Should read:

```
  window.open("/Livie_project1/index.html.html?name="+email,"_blank");
```

You actually don't need specify it, as the default is _blank.

When set to "_self" it will instruct the URL to act on the current window.

Comment: I had corrected,i forgot to edit it here.Its not working and i want to open it in the same window that's why i have given _self

Comment: Need to check that /Livie_project1/index.html url works in your browser. As your saying the server bit works and calls back to your code, I assume the response on 0 is from that url in the window.open?

Comment: it works.I have other pages and they are able to open index.html

Comment: window.open("Livie_project1/index.html") works -  if you skip all your code. Or does that fail?

Comment: it works in either cases.But i dont know why it is failing here

Comment: Did you remove the leading / "/Livie..." "Livie" Have you tried using the full url to the page to see if that works, "http://mydomain/Livie..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139112/discussion-between-aeshna-and-martinwebb).